# How to convert a ePub to CBR or CBZ format? Renaming file extension doesn’t work

Tags: conversion

I thought [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com) did this conversion. But I see that the most Calibre does is convert ePub to Zip.

It renaming the CBR/CBZ but it doesn’t doesn’t work.

Is there any way to convert ePub to CBR or CBZ? Even with the middle step of converting to Zip?

Comment: Besides thinking Calibre did this, what research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: calibre is able to convert into 18 different different formats, not only zip.

Comment: Do you realize that .cbr and .cbz are just renamed .rar and .zip archives which contain pictures?

Comment: It seems that when converting an epub to zip, renaming it to cbz and importing it to calibre, only the images get copied while the text is missing.

Comment: *I know this isn't what you need but there are multiple online 3rd party services online for this purpose*

Comment: @music2myear I searched didn't find either zip to cbr converter or epub to cbr converter.

Comment: @mashuptwice Correct, a rename doesn't work.

Comment: @nadermx https://www.converter365.com/ebook-converter/epub/epub-to-cbz https://cloudconvert.com/cbz-to-epub https://anyconv.com/cbz-to-epub-converter/ Literally on the first site of the search results

Comment: If you don't want to use an online converter, you could use calibre to convert it to pdf, then imagemagicks convert to convert the single pdf's pages to png and throw them in a zip, rename it and you're good to go

Comment: @nadermx this site doesn't recommend services, we are a "how to" site. Have to researched "how to"? In a quick search I found how to  instructions.